# Unable to push docker image with com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven, docker, spring-boot

I started using the `com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin` plugin for building and pushing docker image built from jar files using Spring Boot.

I followed [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) but ran into trouble when bushing by newly built docker image to hub.

Error:

> Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.3.6:push (default-cli) on project demo: Could not push image: denied: requested access to the resource is denied

I read from here that this [is a common problem](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/issues/51) with version 1.3.6 but when I tried different versions of the plugin my IDE told me that they were not found. So I went to [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.spotify/docker-maven-plugin) and found out the overall usage of these plugins is 0.

Im lost here on what to do next.

My goal is the following:
I have a simple Spring Boot RESTful Web Service. I want to containerize this jar (not WAR) and deploy it in AWS. What can I use to do this with Maven?

Thanks!

Comment: First what you mentioned as Maven Central (https://mvnrepository.com/) is *NOT* Maven Central. This is Maven Central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ furthermore for searching you can use https://search.maven.org/ and another thing about the usage. The given URL does not know about any downloads from Maven central so the usage numbers are simply wrong.   Have you checked fabricio docker plugin to use ? And have you checked the docs about authentication?

Comment: you maybe just need to do a "docker login http://server" on your docker registry once on the command line. The plugin will read that authentication token if its located on the default location: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin#authentication - I alsow swtiched to the fabric8 maven plugin - as it has more features - but simple image handling with the spotify plugin was easier and also worked.

Comment: Tried to login with my DockerHub user put the problem persists. What I don't understand is why/what permission spotify plugin needs to build me a Docker image? How can building a simple DockerImage be so difficult, I am doing something wrong but I don't know what.